# formatar timestamp Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice

Existe alguma formula no excel para formatação na coluna timestamp e passar para 1 coluna tipo hora que é o valor que me interessa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Com `Tue Apr 23 2019 11:49:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)` em A2.

A seguinte função:

`=TEXTO(EXT.TEXTO($A2;LOCALIZAR(":";$A2)-2;8);"hh:mm:ss")`

Retorna:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Insiro a fórmula em A2?

Comment: Em outra coluna/célula, em A2 está o dado original